# In a C# List how to select all columns + several custom columns, so that in each row all columns are flat (not nested)?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple `List` that each row of it has **50 columns**. I want return *all 50 columns* **+** *3 custom columns* but i want make each row of the list like a flat (not nested) object.

**Example:**

```
var newList = list.Select(x => new 
    {  x,
       d.CustomColA = x.ColA+10,
       d.CustomColB = x.ColB+30,
       d.CustomColC = x.ColC+50
    });
```

**Result:** It works well **but** each result row is like an nested object:

```
var row = newList.FirstOrDefault();
row.x.ColA
row.x.ColB
row.x.ColC
.....
row.CustomColA 
row.CustomColB 
row.CustomColB
```

**Expected Result:**

```
var row = newList.FirstOrDefault();
row.ColA
row.ColB
row.ColC
.....
row.CustomColA 
row.CustomColB 
row.CustomColB
```

---

I used `dynamic` type and wrote the following code but it did not return expected result:

```
var newList = list.Select(x =>
{
   dynamic d = x;
   d.CustomColA = x.ColA+10;
   d.CustomColB = x.ColB+30;
   d.CustomColC = x.ColC+50;
   return d;
   //return x;
});
```

Result in watch panel: `'newList.FirstOrDefault()' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'`

---

Update:

> **Attention:** I wrote in my question that i have 50 columns and wrote an
> example to show you i do not want name all the columns in the Select!
> (I know I can write name of all 53 column in a Select!) So that is not the correct answer.
>
> **Attention2:** In the real project i have complicated custom columns but i wrote very simple example here to show what i want. Please write your flexible answers. Thank you.

Comment: In the last example, you create a `dynamic d` but `return x`.  Perhaps you should `return d`.

Comment: Yeah what's the point in returning x? makes no sense.

Comment: @JoseLuis It doesn't matter which one gets returned. The issue is that the underlying object needs to support dynamically assigning properties. Only a few objects work. `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject` works for adding properties but since you need the existing properties as well, I suggest using `Newtsonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`.

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised that last one even compiles.  That's not a code block -- it's an object initialization block.

Comment: @JamesCurran That was my bad edit. I fixed it. Many apologies!

Comment: @AluanHaddad the problem with that is that once you assign `x` to `d`, `d` becomes an `x` type, and loses it ExpandoObject capability.

Comment: @JoseLuis, I tested both `x` and `d`. But the result has not any column of data and return this error in watch panel: `'newList.FirstOrDefault()' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'`

Comment: @AluanHaddad the Newtonsoft.Json method has potenial, but wouldn't you need an earlier step, serializing the db object into a JSON string before you parse it into the JObject?  Which seems like an awful lot of work to be doing at runtime (for *every* object), just to avoid having to type out 50 assignements....

Comment: @JamesCurran You are correct, I meant `JObject.FromObject`, not `JObect.Parse`. RAM, what is `x`? What is its type? Also, what are needs to be done to the resulting sequence?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, That makes sense.  (I'm not that familiar with the details of Newtonsoft.Json)

Comment: @AluanHaddad, type of `x` is a Model class, i read its data with EF, in my project. I want know best (fast and simple) way to do this. Do you think using `Newtonsoft.Json` has low cost and high performance or it is just a way?

Comment: Well, it depends. An EF class is going to have circular references, potentially dynamic proxies, and whatnot. You would need to configure the serializer appropriately. You might also consider something like AutoMapper

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I am use AutoMapper in my project and have not any problem to serializing some objects, so if you have a solution please write it as an answer, Thank you. Also I wait until other engineers write their answers then i accept one of them.

Comment: I am actually not particularly familiar with AutoMapper, but here is a link from its wiki that may help [Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping)

Comment: @AluanHaddad, i think if i decide AutoMapper way, I should create a ViewModel include 53 column and Map the new object to the ViewModel, then return the ViewModel object in Select function. Is it possible? If yes then it can be a solution but I think it affect on performance too.

Answer (score 1):

So what you are looking to do is basically map a set of properties. There are libraries for this sort of thing, Automapper is a good one. However, you can also accomplish this yourself with a reflective constructor in an inheriting class. That would look like this:

*Assumptions:*

- Your class with 50 columns is called Cols
- You can inherit from Cols

```
public class CustomColumns : Cols
{
    public int CustomColA { 
        get{
            return this.ColA + 10;
        }
    }
    public int CustomColB { 
        get{
            return this.ColB + 30;
        }
    }
    public int CustomColC { 
        get{
            return this.ColC + 50;
        }
    }
    public CustomColumns(Cols cols)
    {
        string[] localNames = this.GetType().GetMembers().Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).Select(m => m.Name).ToArray();
        string[] ctorNames = cols.GetType().GetMembers().Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).Select(m => m.Name).ToArray();
        string[] names = localNames.Intersect(ctorNames).ToArray();
        foreach (string s in names)
        {
            PropertyInfo propSet = this.GetType().GetProperty(s);
            PropertyInfo propGet = typeof(Cols).GetProperty(s);
            propSet.SetValue(this, propGet.GetValue(cols, null));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demo of this working in dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AKPYQD

Comment: No, I do not want to name each of the 50 columns in the Select!

Comment: Ah, I see. Will refactor.

Comment: This is now a good answer. If you cannot inherit, or do not wish to, you can also use a straight up `IDictionary<string, object>`

Comment: That is a good alternative as well @AluanHaddad, although it would be slightly different usage, it would still work.

Comment: I didn't know about dotnetfiddle, that is awesome. It was fun so made a few changes :) https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y5caut

Comment: `.Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)` in both places. No sense doing a string compare when a simple int compare will do.  (

Comment: @JamesCurran - Fair enough. Edited in.

Comment: @TravisJ I've got this OCD thing about unnecessary string manipulation.

Comment: @TravisJ, What do you think about using AutoMapper to fill the class properties in CustomColumns constructor instead of a reflective constructor?

Comment: @RAM - If you are already using AutoMapper, then that would also be a good option. While it is a nice library, it is also not that widely used so I gave a more general approach. It really comes down to preference. If you have more than 20,000 rows you are working with here, you may also want to benchmark which approach is more time efficient if that becomes an issue (I would also worry about it if you are seeing a computation time of more than 10 milliseconds for a very large set).

Answer (score -2):

Use an anonymous type within the `Select`:

```
var newList = list.Select(x => 
    new
    {
       ColA = x.ColA,
       ColB = x.ColB,
       ColC = x.ColC,
       CustomColA = x.ColA+10;
       CustomColB = x.ColB+30;
       CustomColC = x.ColC+50;
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score -3):

The `.Select()` is creating a new object.  Even if you just wrote:

```
var newList = list.Select(x => new 
{  x  });
```

You've get a nested property.  You are just going to have to explicitly assign every column to a new property (Do you really need all 50 of them?)

Comment: That is not true, there are ways to do this, even using a dictionary and reflection but that should not be directly necessary.